# Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation

Tags: python, classification, tensorboard, sequential

```
My Tensorboard Location: c:\install\python\lib\site-packages
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
File "C:/DATEN/Python/shape-classifier-cnn/cnn.py", line 21, in <module>classifier = Sequential()  

import tensorflow
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
```

As to be a new python user, I don't know anything to change my code in python
Please tell me a code to implement in my python-code to solve this problem